# using Math.max to replace only negative numbers

Tags: java

I am in the process of making a program that calculates based on user input, and is supposed to change negative numbers to a default value without using "if statements "or ": ?". I have tried to use Math.max(input,1), however, this creates a problem for values between 0 and 1. Any recommendations?

Comment: So you'd want to map -0.5 to 1, but 0.5 should stay as 0.5?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes. That is the goal.

Comment: And is there any good reason you *can't* use either `if` or the conditional `?:` operator? That's likely to be *far* simpler than anything else we can come up with.

Comment: Try using Math.abs()

Comment: @joemokenela It should map negative values to 1. Your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: @JonSkeet its just a requirement for this program.

Comment: But why? Often things are stated as requirements which have some underlying cause that can be adjusted. It's a *really* weird requirement to not be able to use the conditional ?: operator.

Comment: @Slaw This is a step in the right direction, however, inputting a value between -1 and 0 produces the absolute value of this variable rather than the default value of 1.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's a requirement to use only what I have been taught, which does not include the ?: operator.

Comment: Right, so this is a homework assignment. When there are unusual requirements, it's always worth explaining the *reason* for those requirements at the same time. (Often the reason can exclude other options too, for example.) I have to say that this is really *not* a good assignment, if all we can do is call methods and use arithmetic. I don't think it's teaching you anything particularly useful - just really convoluted ways of achieving tasks that are much better approached in a different way.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, and thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a silly solution, but try this:

```
while (input < 0)
  input = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user11231654 Then what **are** your apparently inexpressible criteria...? This does exactly what you wanted, even taking into account the silly constraints.

Comment: The criteria for the program is that it simply must replace the negative values with a default value. While I know your suggestion is a possible solution, it was suggested that I use Math.max in conjunction with absolute values to achieve the result.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I can think of one really horrible way of doing it. It relies on using `Math.signum`, which returns -1.0 for negative input, 1.0 for positive input and 0 for zero input. We can use `Math.min(Math.signum(input, 0))` to get -1.0 for negative input, and 0 for zero-or-positive input.

That way, we can clamp the input to a minimum of zero, then subtract that "-1.0 or 0" to avoid changing any non-negative input, but transform negative input to 1.

Here's complete code to do that:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        testValue(-1.5);
        testValue(-0.5);
        testValue(0);
        testValue(0.5);
        testValue(1.5);
    }

    private static void testValue(double input) {
        double result = transformInput(input);
        System.out.println(input + " -> " + result);
    }

    private static double transformInput(double input) {
        double clampedValue = Math.max(input, 0);
        double clampedSign = Math.min(Math.signum(input), 0);
        return clampedValue - clampedSign;
    }
}
```

But as I noted in comments, this is a *horrible* question, which is *much* better achieved with the `?:` operator, and I question the wisdom of whoever set you this assignment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: @user11231654 but please, never use this style in real code, it is almost impossible to understand without some time effort/testing/comments.(despite the good naming of variables/methods). The solution using `if` would be so simple and mostly understandable by anyone...  (BTW I'm pretty sure that `signum` is less known than `if`)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: I'd say that the `?:` operator would be even simpler: `double result = input < 0 ? 1 : input;`

Comment: sure, but I did avoid it (in the comment) since not that understandable by some (non-)programmer

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not as clean as I want (even I don't like how convoluted it is), but it works ;)

```
Math.round(((Math.max(input+1, 1)-Math.signum(input+Math.abs(input)))*100))/100.0
```

Input

> 5
>   0.5
>   0.3
>   -0.2
>   -0.5
>   -2

Output

> 5.0
>   0.5
>   0.3
>   1.0
>   1.0
>   1.0

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Math.max(..,..)` you can make your own method to implement your logic and return the desired result as below.

```
  public static double mapInput(double input) {

    return Math.max(input, (input < 0 ? 1 : input));
  }
```

Comment: You're using a ternary, which is "not allowed"

Comment: The requirement says `without using "if statements "or ": ?"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, however it is a requirement to replace the negative values with the default value without using the ?: function. It was hinted that using Math.max in conjunction with Math.abs is a solution that adheres to the rules.

Comment: ternary is not allowed but in the sample, he is using max function of Math class so we can make our own to implement this logic.